# calculating number of active employees for partial months

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of employees on a project and I have the following formula that calculates the number of employees active each month:

`=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($A$20#),1,0),($L$1#>=OFFSET($A$20#,0,3,,1))*($L$1#<=OFFSET($A$20#,0,4,,1)))`

Where **$L$1#** is defined by `=EDATE(01/01/2020, SEQUENCE(1, 6, 0))` and **$A$20#** refernces the first entry in a dataset of employees as below:

| Employee | Role | Discipline | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Senior Programmer | Programming | 12/01/2020 | 06/05/2020 |
| Dave | Mid Level Programmer | Programming | 01/02/2020 | 30/05/2020 |
| Peter | Senior Programmer | Programming | 01/01/2020 | 31/01/2020 |
| Jack | Junior Programmer | Programming | 01/02/2020 | 30/06/2020 |
| Richard | Senior Artist | Art | 01/03/2020 | 30/04/2020 |
| Rodney | Lead QA | QA | 01/03/2020 | 30/06/2020 |

This formula above will only cope with those employees on a project from the start of the month. I'd like it to increment the number of employees even if they are on it for a single day in the start month so giving the following result:

|  | Jan 20 | Feb 20 | Mar 20 | Apr 20 | May 20 | Jun 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Active Staff | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 2 |

I tried modifying the formula to check if the **Start Date** is between the month start and month end defined by **$L$1#** but unfortunately this doesn't like the use of **$L$1#** in the EOMONTH function:

`=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($A$20#),1,0),(AND((OFFSET($A$20#,0,3,,1)>=$L$1#),(OFFSET($A$20#,0,3,,1)<=EOMONTH($L$1#,0))))*($L$1#<=OFFSET($A$20#,0,4,,1)))`

How would I go about adjusting the above to work with **$L$1#**?

Comment: Is `A20#` one column only?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `L1` be `=EDATE(DATEVALUE("1/1/2020"), SEQUENCE(1, 6, 0))` ?

Comment: A20 is the top left cell of the sample data in the question

Comment: L1 actually references a cell for the date and I pasted the date into the formula for the question to simplify

Comment: The reason I was asking about A20# being one column is to easily avoid the use of OFFSET which is volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following in cell `G1`:

```
=LET(set, A2:E7, starts, INDEX(set,,4), ends, INDEX(set,,5), SOMs, G1:L1,
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
  overlaps, FILTER(starts, (starts <= EOM) * (ends >= SOM), 0),
  ROWS(overlaps)
 )))
)
```

There are multiple ways to achieve the same, for example using `SUMPRODUCT` or just `SUM`:

```
=LET(set, A2:E7, starts, INDEX(set,,4), ends, INDEX(set,,5), SOMs, G1:L1,
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
  SUMPRODUCT((starts <= EOM) * (ends >= SOM))
 )))
)
```

The main idea is to check for overlap condition of two intervals `A`, `B`:

```
AND(startA <= endB, endA >= startB)
```

**Note**: None of the above approaches use `OFFSET` a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function) (usually not recommended or to be avoided when it is possible)

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Comment: Nice one. And to answer Automation Monkeys question why EDATE didn't work: EDATE doesn't take an array sideways. You need to transpose it in order to work and you could transpose the result back: `=TRANSPOSE(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(L1#),0))`

Comment: I see @P.b I was trying to respond to the requirement, and I saw a volatile function such as `OFFSET`, so I took another approach. I still need to check the result, because it is not the same, I am reviewing any issue with the dates that were correctly converted to my locale.

Comment: Now the result is the expected, when copy dates to excel it doesn't work well with different locale, so it has to be adjusted